# Discord: send an embed message with 2 buttons (with url link assigned)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I make a script who send an embed message in chan.
I need to send with this message 2 buttons, with link assigned, when click on these.
How to make this on my script python please?
My code actually:

```
embed = DiscordEmbed(title='> :incoming_envelope: __Posté par '+(author)+'__', description=content, color='03b2f8')
embed.set_author(name='DEALABS (Topic EDP)', url='https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/le-topic-des-erreurs-de-prix-1056379?page=999', icon_url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/langfr-225px-Flag_of_France.svg.png')
embed.set_thumbnail(url=link_img)
#embed.set_image(url=link_img)
embed.set_footer(text='DEALABS (Topic EDP)')
embed.set_timestamp()
embed.add_embed_field(name='> :pushpin: __Lien erreur de prix:__', value=link_edp)
embed.add_embed_field(name='> :bell: __Tag:__', value=':orange_circle: [@here](https://7e01f9c8.eu.jeedom.link/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=e6FZdh5wGTreFrUnW0REfnaVdb5W57GB&type=scenario&id=6&action=start) - :red_circle: [@everyone](https://7e01f9c8.eu.jeedom.link/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=e6FZdh5wGTreFrUnW0REfnaVdb5W57GB&type=scenario&id=6&action=start)')
#embed.add_embed_field(name='Field 3', value='amet consetetur')
#embed.add_embed_field(name='Field 4', value='sadipscing elitr')

webhook.add_embed(embed)
if 'amazon.fr' or 'amazon.de' or 'amazon.es' or 'amazon.co.uk' in content:
    response = webhook.execute()

driver.close();
```

And what i want:
[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Do read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We won't provide the code for you rather help you with your code. You can use an external library such as ```discord-components``` to implement buttons in ```discord.py```